# trim end of the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trim empty string from end of the string.
For example; txtSearch value is 'test      ' How to replace it 'test'?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" onKeyDown="return search_onKeyDown(event);" onKeyUp="search_onKeyUp(event);"
```

Comment: To explain the downvotes - did you do your research before asking? Trivial google search should answer this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.trim()` in jQuery.It will trim all the first and last spaces

[**.trim()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
$.trim("    hello, how are you?    ");
```

OUTPUT:  `"hello, how are you?"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use C# [TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) function in code